# Port configuration for USB 3.0 Camera setup

Tags: linux, networking, usb, usb-3, camera

I'm building a setup with 10 USB 3.0 5MP color cameras and need to connect all of it to a single desktop computer running latest Linux kernel.

By trial and error, I've found out that 3-4 cameras per USB hub is the limit of what a single port can handle. Therefore I can have 3 hubs to cover for 10 cameras.

My question is: is there a better configuration? More notably, is there a 10 port USB 3.0 hub with ports grouped to several output ports so one can at least use single hub for all cameras?

thanks!